# How to randomly select and plot a csv file from a folder

Tags: csv, pythontex

I have `data1.csv`, `data2.csv`, and `data3.csv` in a folder.

I use [`pythontex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) to randomly select a number from 1 to 3.

```
\begin{pycode}
list = random.sample(range(1, 3), 3)
select = list[0]
\end{pycode}
```

Then in the document I tried to use the command

```
\addplot table [] {data\py{select}.csv};
```

but it didn't work.

How can we manage to read a file name `data#.csv` with `#` randomly selected like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expansion issue. The file argument must be fully expandable, so you need to have a macro or number with the already expanded random before using `\addplot`. You could, e.g., use [`random`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/random):

```
% Somewhere in the document preamble:
\input{random.tex}
\newcount\randomselect
```

and try something like

```
\setrannum{\randomselect}{1}{3}
\edef\randomdata{data\the\randomselect.csv}
```

somewhere before `\addplot`. To be able to use

```
\addplot table [] {\randomdata}
```

Here a short example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents*}{data1.csv}
1 1
5 1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
1 1
5 2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{data3.csv}
1 1
5 3
\end{filecontents*}

\input{random}
\newcount\randomselect
\newcommand*{\randomdata}{NotInitialized}
\newcommand*{\newrandomdata}[2]{%
  \setrannum{\randomselect}{#1}{#2}%
  \edef\randomdata{data\the\randomselect.csv}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \newrandomdata{1}{3}%
    \addplot [red] table {\randomdata};
    \newrandomdata{1}{3}%        
    \addplot [blue] table {\randomdata};
    \newrandomdata{1}{3}%
    \addplot [green] table {\randomdata};
    \legend{first,second,third}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another really nice suggestion would be to use sequences of [`expl3`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel). With this you would not need to have numeric files names:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents*}{dataA.csv}
1 1
5 1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{dataX.csv}
1 1
5 2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{data3.csv}
1 1
5 3
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \my_data_files_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \my_data_file_seq { dataA.csv, dataX.csv, data3.csv }
\newcommand*{\randomdata}{\seq_rand_item:N \my_data_file_seq}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [red] table {\randomdata};
    \addplot [blue] table {\randomdata};
    \addplot [green] table {\randomdata};
    \legend{first,second,third}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, with both suggestions, don't expect much randomness with only three numbers! Real randomness needs a wide range. So this example sometimes shows three lines, sometimes only two or one. And sometimes several runs of the example show the same result.

Comment: I just follow your suggestion but it still doesn't work for me. Could you put a short example?

Comment: @HanaEnna As already told: It is always better, if you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) into the question. We can use such a MWE not only to reproduce the problem, but also to find a solution and to show our suggestion.

Comment: Very nice, all worked now. I wonder whether we can catch which file was selected so that we can do sth. else. I am trying to use the exam class to make a multiple choice question. Let's say Data1.csv is in fact the data of y=e^x, Data2.csv is for y = ln(x),... So if Data1 is selected in this random process then the correct answer (among other options) would be y=e^x. Usually I use pythontex to do this. I did try "if \the\randomselect == 1:" in pycode but it didn't work since python does not understand "\the\randomselect".